# Elsevier rticle not rendering affiliation properly

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, rticles

I am using the elsevier rticle template to prepare a paper with rmarkdown. When I knit it, commas do not get rendered in the institutional affiliation. This can be reproduced by installing rticles, creating a rmarkdown from the elsevier template, and knitting it. As can be seen below, the commas between Department, Street etc fail to render out of the box.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a raw attribute in the yaml block to properly format the latex code used to specify affiliations. Here I modified the yaml block in the rticles template:

````yaml
title: Short Paper
author:
  - name: Alice Anonymous
    email: alice@example.com
    affiliation: a
    correspondingauthor: true
    footnote: 1
  - name: Bob Security
    email: bob@example.com
    affiliation: b
  - name: Cat Memes
    email: cat@example.com
    affiliation: b
    footnote: 2
  - name: Derek Zoolander
    email: derek@example.com
    affiliation: b
    footnote: 2
address:
  - code: a
    address:  |
      ```{=latex}
      organization={Some Institute of Technology},
      addressline={Street}, 
      city={City}, state={State}, postcode={Zip},
      country={United States}
      ```
  - code: b
    address:  |
      ```{=latex}
      organization={Another University},
      addressline={Street}, 
      city={City}, state={State}, postcode={Zip},
      country={United States}
      ```
````

[image: title block]